# iOS App relauches instead of resuming

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I'm wondering that when App shut down itself.( My app is a game made using cocos2d.) and when I return to game from others(like a mail, whatever), sometimes It continue as I was using, but sometimes It restart itself.

first time I though this is a one of memory problems. but It's not. It happen too though memory is enough.

Answer (score 2):

When you app enters the background if the device determines that it needs some more memory it may kill backgrounded apps with out warning.

Extract from iOS App Programmgin Guide:

> Even if you develop your app using iOS SDK 4 and later, you must still
>   be prepared for your app to be killed without any notification. The
>   user can kill apps explicitly using the multitasking UI. In addition,
>   if memory becomes constrained, the system might remove apps from
>   memory to make more room. Suspended apps are not notified of
>   termination but f your app is currently running in the background
>   state (and not suspended), the system calls the
>   applicationWillTerminate: method of your app delegate. Your app cannot
>   request additional background execution time from this method.

Comment: Thanks very much letting me know exactly what happened. hm.... It's probably true. but I think I faced a couple of cases that It's not killed because of memory. because I killed the others to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use core data to save the state of your application!

Here is a tutorial: [Core Data Tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008305)